# Extract specific value from many array and then put them as an array spark sql

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, extract

I want to extract some certain values in many arrays and then put them in the other array

[image: 1]

Comment: 1 - please don't post links to images (for multiple reasons). 2. This isn't a homework service. Show us what you've tried, ask specific questions, and folks will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a homework task, good luck explaining this to your professor ;)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("a,b,c,d;e,f,g,h;,,,,",),
     ("a,b,c,d;e,f,g,h;k,l,m,n;,,,,",)],
    ["col_1"])

df = df.withColumn("col_2", F.expr(
    """
    aggregate(
        regexp_extract_all(col_1, '(\\\\w);', 1),
        '',
        (acc, x) -> concat(acc, rpad(x, 2, ','))
    )
    """
))
df.show(truncate=0)
# +----------------------------+------+
# |col_1                       |col_2 |
# +----------------------------+------+
# |a,b,c,d;e,f,g,h;,,,,        |d,h,  |
# |a,b,c,d;e,f,g,h;k,l,m,n;,,,,|d,h,n,|
# +----------------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A way which is probably easier to explain to your professor;

Input dataset:

```
+-----------------------+
|col_1                  |
+-----------------------+
|a,b,c,d;e,f,g,h;,,,    |
|a,b,c,d;e,f,g,h;k,l,m,n|
+-----------------------+
```

Transformations:

```
df1 = df1
  // explode in ; first
  .withColumn("col_2", split(col("col_1"), ";"))
  // map each element to the third element of the exploded array
  .withColumn("col_2", expr("transform(col_2, x -> split(x, ',')[3])"))
  // join the result with commas
  .withColumn("col_2", array_join(col("col_2"), ","))
```

Final output:

```
+-----------------------+-----+
|col_1                  |col_2|
+-----------------------+-----+
|a,b,c,d;e,f,g,h;,,,    |d,h, |
|a,b,c,d;e,f,g,h;k,l,m,n|d,h,n|
+-----------------------+-----+
```